# Boot Repair doesn't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, restore

first at all excuse my English.

I am using Ubuntu 21.10 dual boot with Windows. My problem started when in the Ubuntu terminal I entered the following command:

```bsh
mv /* /folder/folder
```

I was in the folder Download, trying to move all files inside to this /folder/folder. Then the computer froze and I restarted with the shutdown button.

When it turned on again it only ran `grub`. I did not find solutions to repair from there, so I loaded a "Live USB" with Lubuntu (i think) and Boot-Repair (these two come from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)).

This is the [Boot](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/pRpBRTKBC6/) Info that came from Boot-Repair.

When running Boot-Repair (Recommended Repair) it shows me the following message:

"Please enable a repository containing the [linux-generic] packages in the software sources of unknown Linux distribution (nvme0n1p8). Then try again"

nvme0n1p8 is the disk where I installed Ubuntu 21.10.

One more thing. If I change the boot order in UEFI I can login in Windows 10.

I think that I deleted files from Ubuntu when I ran mv command. The Boot Info of the nvme0n1p8 drive is empty. I have no backup of Ubuntu, my external disk crashed, sorry.

EDIT. I try the idea of [Joepie Es](https://askubuntu.com/a/1402917/913625) with testdisk in a liveUSB with Lubuntu. It's only allow me see the Ubuntu partition with EFI GPT option (when you choose the partition table), i can't see the partition if i choose Intel. The file tree are incomplete, specially, there are not `/home` directory. There no red files (the ones that suposed that `testdisk` shows when find deleted files).

Thanks for your help!

END. Sadly i reinstall Ubuntu. I can't find the files loosed with `testdisk`.

Comment: It appears that you destroyed your system with that command, especially if you ran it with sudo. /* does not mean the contents of the Downloads folder. Boot Repair can't fix that kind of damage. I would reinstall, but perhaps someone will answer with a less drastic fix.

Comment: It's wasn't with sudo. I would prefer not lost my files reinstalling Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recover the files by using the 'live-lubuntu' to a partition where your Ubuntu-installation NOT was located. After that you can install it again.

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if im wrong.

Use `rsync -r ~/Downloads /folder/folder`. It's mean copying all files or contents inside folder download and paste it to `/folder/folder`. By the way use `~/` for interaction with your home directory.

After run the command you can manually delete the source files or use `rsync -r --remove-source-files ~/Downloads /folder/folder` It's will be delete source files automatically.

For your Ubuntu 21.10 maybe you can try reinstall again. Hope this helps (:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't boot in Ubuntu, so I think that's I can't run rsync. :)

Comment: Hint lookup what the / symbol means in Ubuntu.

Comment: @matiasdiez I mean use `rsync` instead `mv` if just want to move the contents inside the folder after you can boot to your Ubuntu again. Cause your root `/` directory is missing and it's need to be reinstall again or run backup if possible. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help SunnUlya. Sadly i reinstall Ubuntu. Because i don't find the files loosed. And i don't know how could run `rsync`without having the possibility to boot in the Ubuntu (after run `mv` i can't boot in the system again). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By running that command you tried to move everything from the root folder (`/*`) into the `/folder/folder` including the boot, var, proc, home, etc. folders. If you ran that command without sudo you must have received a lot of failures. I suspect you ran the cammand with sudo or as root.

At this point I would recommend you backup your files through a live USB and reinstall Ubuntu.

That said, you might try to copy all the erraneously moved folders back to root from the live environment and reboot, but it is not guaranteed to work.